# Correct format for [Plural noun] of [physical quantity] [values]

Tags: grammar, sentence

Which phrase is correct?

1. Two lines of length 9 cm and 10 cm.
2. Two lines of lengths 9 cm and 10 cm.

Answer (score 2):

That's a very awkward construction, "of length."
You would say, "Two lines, 9 cm and 10 cm long,..." which actually isn't a sentence. There's no verb in there.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification. The actual sentence was "The transistors of length 10 cm and 9 cm have demonstrated a linear change of 50% and 76%, respectively." What would be the best way to put it?

Answer (score 1):

As a math teacher, I'd say, "Please draw two lines, one 9 cm long and one 10 cm long."
As Barn and Phil noted, "of length" doesn't sound right.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! What if the physical quantity if different? Eg: dielectric constant. "We have two materials of dielectric constant 7 and 8." Does that still sound weird?

Comment: Not to me. Keep in mind, English is the tool that serves us, not the other way around. A person in a particular tech field might adopt a way of speaking that doesn't parse out to perfect English, but the point is to communicate unambiguously. I understood your quote. Once you name the materials, I'd be inclined to say "remind me which is which?" i.e. I don't know which one has the 7 vs the 8. All I remember is Germanium is about 16.

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. I guess my original question was whether to use "dielectric constant" or "dielectric constants" in the sentence "We have two materials of dielectric constant(s) 7 and 8."

Comment: See? I didn't even notice that. Nor would a student or coworker. I suppose the plural is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The plural would be correct. "We have two materials of dielectric constants 7 and 8." The nouns should agree with the plural verb "have". So you "have materials...of constants...".

And the original sentence> "The transistors, 10 cm and 9 cm long, have demonstrated a linear change of 50% and 76%, respectively."

Hope that helps.